# GPU acceleration crashes website

Tags: google-chrome, css

I am running into a random issue in a website that I am working. This website contains many images and some images are 1Mb in size or bigger. The site also uses some CSS3 tricks, like 3D rotations.

Since I added this 3D CSS stuff, I noticed a problem in Google Chrome where some random areas in the website are not rendered.

This is a screen-shoot of how the site should be rendered, the green lines are because I've enabled the "Composited render layer borders" on chrome://flags:
[image]

And this is how it get rendered when the issue happens:

[image]

This white squares appear randomly and they can disappear or reappear in another place if the scroll the website. I also noticed that this problem is more common in lower-end computers so I my guess is that somehow Chrome is running out of GPU memory.

Why this problem happens? and is the any workaround for it (besides disabling the 3d CSS)?

In case it helps, this is the website:
http://colocation.cubo.cc/cheetos/masterbrand/

## Update:

- I raised a [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121779) for the Chrome team.
- I couldn't reproduce this problem in the Chrome Canary.

Comment: Regardless of the workaround, can you please file this as an issue on http://crbug.com/new

Comment: Have you updated your video drivers recently?

Comment: @DarthContinent Yes, I tested it in OS X 10.6.8 with updated drivers, but I don't that's relavant since I could reproduce the problem in other computers

Comment: @Kinlan Thanks for the suggestion, I filed an issue for the Chrome team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Chrome Issue, and its fixed now:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121779

I can only congratulate the Chrome team for pushing bugfixes so fast, I wish IE was like this.