# Chrome 18 rendering artifacts around form elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, rendering

After upgrading to Chrome 18 on OSX 10.7.3, we started noticing fleeting rendering artifacts seemingly related to form elements:

[image]

They come and go during scrolling, it seems. I've been testing in a variety of other OS/Browser environments and have been unable to reproduce this, nor had it happened in previous versions of Chrome.

This is a mature, stable web app with fairly complicated HTML/CSS.  I haven't been able to produce a simple test fiddle that reproduces this.

Anyone else seeing issues?  Can you think of a possible HTML/CSS cause and not a Chrome bug?

Comment: Chrome 19 is out on the beta channel - might be worth seeing if that has the same issues

Comment: Good idea @Mikey.  Just tried beta channel and couldn't reproduce the bug.  Assuming this is their bug and moving on with life.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I also noticed that Chrome 18 displays artifacts in some pages, but this only happens when that page is GPU accelerated. I asked a similar question a few days ago:

[GPU acceleration crashes website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999418/gpu-acceleration-crashes-website)

Chrome enables the hardware acceleration when it detects 3D transforms in your CSS.

You can go to [chrome://flags](http://chrome://flags) and enable the "Composited render layer borders" option, if you see green squares all around your page thats because some CSS rule is causing your page to be hardware accelerated. You can try removing any 3D CSS rules or assign a higher z-index to these elements. It usually helps.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't get any green borders after I enabled the flag, and I can't think of any CSS that would cause Chrome to think there are 3D transforms.  Might be relevant, tho, thx!

Comment: You can also try enabling the FPS counter. It only appears when the page has some hardware acceleration

Comment: Tried that one too - once I got into the /flags I went nuts! Didn't show up.  :/